# How to get Hyper-V VM's IP address with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm trying to acquire my VM's IP address using this code:

`$vm.NetworkAdapters | Select-Object IPAddresses`

The output is:

```
IPAddresses
-----------
{}
{}
{}
```

For some reason, I can't get back the IP addresses of the VM... It's up and running and it has network connection.

Comment: can you try `Get-VM | ?{$_.ReplicationMode -ne “Replica”} | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select VMName, IPAddresses, Status` or `Get-VM -Name MyVM | Select Name, @{N="IP";E={@($_.Guest.IPAddress)}}`

Comment: Both returned empty IP fields

Comment: To me @Quit3Simpl3, that would mean you haven't set up an IP on the VM's NIC - can you manually search for this and confirm the IP?

Comment: @Matthew Is it possible to check that outside of the guest OS? Inside it has an IP address and internet connection (web surfing is possible). Also I can ping it from my machine (the host).

Comment: You would need to check this within the VM itself, likely it has no IPv4 IP or the issue is PS does not have the permission to pull this information but both suggested by myself and richard should be able to pull this information.

Comment: Yeah so it has IPv4 address. Is it possible to check whether powershell has some permission limitations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so apparently running this **does** work:

```
get-vm | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters | select vmname, macaddress, switchname, ipaddresses
```

But first I had to install Linux Integration Services on my Ubuntu machine:
1. Run:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install linux-azure
```

choose y (yes) when prompted.

2. Run:

   `# reboot`

Thanks everyone for your help

Comment: The first commend works perfectly inside Windows powerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The Hyper-V VM has to be running for the IP address information to be available. If your VM is running try this

```
Get-VM -Name W19ND01 | 
select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | 
select VMname, Name, IPAddresses
```